# How did 'milieu' evolve to mean 'social environment'?

Tags: etymology

What's an intuitive derivation behind [ODO's definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/milieu?q=milieux) that helps to remember its meaning:

> **milieu** = A person’s social environment:
>
> [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=milieu&searchmode=none): "surroundings," 1877, from French milieu, "middle, medium, mean," literally "middle place" (12c.), from **mi** "middle" (from Latin medius; see medial (adj.)) **+ lieu** "place" (see lieu).

Yet how does 'middle place' induce the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant meaning in French (that is indeed listed in etymonline) is *medium*.

If you look in the French Larousse from 1863 (via [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=H60_AAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Larousse+1863&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kOIuVPevF-O1sQT3nIDYDQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=milieu&f=false)), it says:

> *Phys.* Fluide qui environne les corps: *l'air est le milieu dans lequel nous vivons.*

This is clearly the meaning adapted into English. Translated, this means

> *Phys.* Fluid that surrounds bodies: *air is the **milieu** in which we live.*

Surprisingly, the translation of this physics sense of the French word *milieu* is the English word *medium*, which also translates the quite different everyday French meaning of *milieu* (ie = *middle* in English). One might think that the French and English physicists had been talking to each other.

Of course, you then get the questions of how the word *medium* came to have this meaning, and whether *medium* was used for this in English before *milieu* in French, or vice versa.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=medium&allowed_in_frame=0) says:

> Meaning "intermediate agency, channel of communication" is from c.1600.

So my guess is that a substance through which waves are carried is called a *medium* because it is an intermediate between the sender and the receiver. And this meaning got broadened to be much more general, including (for example) a substance in which bacteria are cultured.

Comment: I’m a bit surprised that they describe air as a _fluid_. I mean, I know it rains a lot in England, but still.

Comment: @Janus: the 1867 Larousse gives *air* as an example of a fluid in its definition of *fluid*. So it didn't mean exactly the same thing in French as it does in English. So in French in 1867, *un liquide* and *un gaz* were both examples of fluids. And in fact, looking at the current Larousse, that's still true today.

Comment: I suppose both gases and liquids _flow_ …

Comment: +1. Thank you. Would you please clarify 'Surprisingly, the translation of ... different everyday meaning of *milieu*.'? In the first (independent) clause, are you saying that milieu (Fr) => medium (Eng)? Then what happens to medium (En)? Are you referring to the English or French *milieu* as the last word in that sentence?

Comment: @Upvote: according to the OED, *medium* has meant *liquid or gas through which waves travel* since the 17th century. I suspect this term (broadened to mean *enveloping liquid or gas*) was translated into French as *milieu*, which word it in turn got appropriated into English in 1877 as *social environment.*

Comment: Thank you again. Would you please clarify what is 'the quite different everyday meaning of *milieu*'? I can't differentiate if you're referring to the English or French *milieu*?

Comment: The everyday meaning of *milieu* in French is *middle*. The everyday meaning of *medium* in English is also *middle*.

Comment: Thank you again. Please forgive my ancillary edit, but feel free to edit it